# hide all divs onload jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to hide all the divs on load, Actually not really all divs but only those with specific ID

I have this case:

HTML:

```
<div id="dialog-'+this.id+'" style= "margin-left:25px; width:500px; height:180px"></div>
<img src="images/map.jpg"  id = "mapicon" onClick="showhide('+this.id+');">
```

JS:

```
function showhide(id){
    $("#dialog-"+id).toggle();
}
```

As I create all those divs using loop when the page enters, and what I want is, hide all those divs that starts with "dialog-". so then once I click map icon it shows the specific div with specific id.

I was thinking to make a loop within the jQuery onload page but still I don't know what is my end ID and I am not sure if that is a good way to do. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "attribute starts with" selector :

```
$('[id^="dialog-"]').hide();
```

It's also available in CSS3, so if older browsers aren't an issue, you don't need javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try with .**hide**() like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div[id^="dialog-"]').hide();
});
```

This will select all the divs  those ids will starts with "dialog-"

Comment: Just try with my edit...I replaced single quotes to double for the id selection...

Comment: That's very strange actually, bc I also think this way should be working

Comment: And also try to select like id^="dialog"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31867/discussion-between-lulzim-and-gautam3164)

Comment: Hey Gautam3164 , I fixed the issue, and its interesting you know how???
by adding display:none; for each div. So that worked, I am not sure how efficient is this solution but this was the only one i came across...

Answer (score 0):

you can do this -

```
$('div[id^="dialog-"]').hide();
```

- http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 0):

By adding

```
display:none; on style="" tag,
```

this fixed the problem...

I just wanted to let the others know if they face this problem or would also want to know how efficient is this way...

Comment: You can also add some class to all those divs , like `<div id="dialog-1" class="hidden"></div>` and then in css add: `.hidden{display:none;}` - that's quite common case, i.e. Twitter bootstrap and probably many other frameworks add this automatically

Comment: yes this can work too, but its almost the same logic as i did above

Comment: Of course you're right, but that's what CSS was made for :) So later on, if you decide to make all those elements not really hidden, but let's say slightly transparent, you will not have to find all occurences of `style="display: none"` and change it to `style="opacity:0.1"`, but you would just change signle line in css.